# Makefile with pthread won't compile properly with multiple versions

Tags: c++, pthreads, makefile

For a project, I have to create a simple makefile for the source code which includes pthreads and command line arguments (if those matter to include).

The first version of the makefile that didn't work was this:

```
 mr: mr.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -pthread mr.o -o mr
 mr.o: mapred.cc
    g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c mapred.cc
 clean:
    rm *.o mr
```

and I got the following error that the object file did not exist?
[image]

So then I decided to flip the two first statements around:

```
mr.o: mapred.cc
   g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c mapred.cc 
mr: mr.o
   g++ -std=c++11 -pthread mr.o -o mr 
clean:
   rm *.o mr
```

and it compiles, sort of? All I get in the terminal is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c mapred.cc
```

and nothing else. When I look at what files were created, all I see is a new file `mapred.o` created but no executable. So no errors but not fully completed. If you guys have any tips to help me out that would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an explicit output name with the `-o` option, then the compiler will name object file the same as the source file but with an `.o` suffix.

In your case, the command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c mapred.cc
```

will create an object file named `mapread.o`.

Either use `mapread.o` for your target names and when linking, or use the `-o` option:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c mapred.cc -o mr.o
```

---

As for your second problem, unless you specify an explicit target when invoking `make`, it will only use the *first* target and nothing else.